# Clone an AWS ELB... onto a new subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-load-balancer

Is there a way to clone an AWS ELB onto a different subnet?

I have an ELB that's part of a large stack.  It was mistakenly created as an internal ELB, rather than internet-facing.  It doesn't look like there's a configuration option to change that config, after the fact.

I'm wondering if there's a way to either:

1) Clone the entire ELB (with backend instances, health checks, etc), only create it with an internet-facing scheme.

or

2) Change the scheme without recreating the ELB

Answer (score 0):

If you created the ELB using a tool like CloudFormation or Terraform then you would just modify a setting and update your stack. Behind the scenes, the tool would delete the old ELB and create a new one.

If you created the ELB manually, then you will need to create a new one manually, and copy over all the settings manually. There is no ELB "clone" feature in AWS.